# How to have a button clicked automatically via Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to write an apex code that will click a button automatically.
Is it possible, if so hen how to accomplish it?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE. I have a feeling this may be an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info). Try asking about what you're trying to do, instead of asking about a specific way to try and do something. There's probably a way you can achieve the same effect as what you're looking for, but this approach won't work.

Answer (score 1):

No. Apex Code runs on the server, while buttons run on the client. While the client can call methods on the server, the server can't directly call methods on the client, including clicking a button.

Comment: Well...if it's a custom `Visualforce` button, it's not outside the realm of possibility. It's just too unclear as currently written what the goal is.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You could call the code the button calls, but you still can't literally "click" the button, at least not without rigging up additional JavaScript on the client anyways.